# Music of Yemenite Jews: Baladi vs Shammi

Tags: music, trop-cantillation, yemenite-temani

I know there are differences of prayer and practice between Baladi and Shammi for Yemenites. But is the music the same? Are the melodies of the te'amim the same?

Comment: shaami have changed their tune compared to baladi but its similar. they also breakup the parosho in the safaradi way not the teimoni way. music is the same for the most part except for obvious qabbalistic poetry

Comment: Do you know any recordings of the ta'amei ha miqroth for Baladi?

Comment: for toro or nakh?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/user/matanyahacohen/videos nakh https://www.youtube.com/user/eliran553/videos toro

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J9PejgTqFnE